# The method create(File) is undefined for the type FileRepositoryBuilder even though it has a create method

Tags: java, git, jgit, jgitflow-maven-plugin

The following part of the code

```
Repository repository = FileRepository.create(new File(localPath, ".git"));
repository.create();
```

throws an error. But

[image]

has a method by that name under JGit `FileRepository`.

Comment: You a probably using a different version of JGit than the JavaDoc is targeted at. Please provide more details about which version of JGit you use and how you manage dependencies (e.g. Maven, OSGi, manually). You may also want to look into [this article](http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/10/28/an-introduction-to-the-jgit-sources/) that helps to set up JGit.

Comment: Besides your current problem, you shouldn't be accessing `FileRepository`. It is part of an internal package and may change without prior notice. See this article for [how to access a repository with JGit](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/09/22/access-git-repository-with-jgit/)